# Form.term.data returns nothing

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, cjk

I'm making a Flask app for an online dictionary, but the FlaskForm I've made doesn't return anything when submitted. Here's my app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "bbe039da711aa33120ffe25823ae104d1daa0d8efc3e8b3ceb37a4819bf3f695"


class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    term = StringField(label=('Search for:'), validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label=('Search'))


d = {
    "我": {
        "eng": "I, me",
        "pin": "ng4"
    },
    "你": {
        "eng": "you",
        "pin": "nyi4"
    }
}


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        hanterm = form.term.data
        postdata = d[hanterm]
        return render_template("results.html", title=hanterm, postdata=postdata)
    return render_template("index.html", title="Search", form=form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My index.html (which contains the template that results.html extends from):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-section mt-2 ml-2">
        <form method="GET" autocomplete="off" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Search term:</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
                    {{ form.term.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.term(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my results.html:

```html
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p>Reading: {{ postdata["pin"] }}</p>
    <p>English: {{ postdata["eng"] }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The user enters a Han character into the input field and submits, and the character should then be asssigned to `hanterm` and its dictionary assigned to `postdata`, and then `postdata` is sent to results.html so that its values can be printed.

E.g. if I typed 我, `hanterm='我'` and

```py
postdata = {
        "eng": "I, me",
        "pin": "ng4"
    }
```

whose values are then printed in results.html.

However, when I submit, nothing happens. When I tried to print form.term.data, I got nothing. I previously had two routes - one for the home page and the other for the page of results, but I kept on getting Keyerrors and thought that was cause of the hanterm variable not going to the results function (which contained these bits:

```py
        hanterm = form.term.data
        postdata = d[hanterm]
        return render_template("results.html", title=hanterm, postdata=postdata)
```

and the render_template for results.html), so I tried using global variables, session variables etc. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your HTML form specifies `method="GET"` while your Python is checking for `if request.method == "POST":`

If you are using `GET`, the form data is contained in the request URL, so you should be accessing it in Flask with something like `request.args.get("term")`.

I would recommend not using a flask form for a search function but instead using a simple HTML `GET` form and checking for request arguments on every request to the page, something like this:

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def search():
    hanterm = request.args.get("term")
    if hanterm:
        return render_template(
            "results.html",
            title=hanterm,
            postdata=d[hanterm],
        )
    return render_template("index.html", title="Search")
```